# How to mute Sliding Friction

Tags: friction

I solve rubik's cubes and do it a lot. However, a lot of people around me get annoyed when I do it because it gets really scratchy when I go fast. I know this is because of the sliding friction between the two cubes sliding past each other. That's why I want to find a way to sound proof the sides of the cube, or insert some sort of sound absorbing foam inside the cubes. I'm not really sure which or what I would need to do to make this happen. Please help, since I'm not sure what I need to do something like this. I also need it to be really small, and something that wouldn't add to much more depth to the cube, since that would limit its speed. Thanks so much.

PS:Sorry if I put this in the wrong section. I'm not really sure where it would be put.

Comment: Did you try using a little bit of silicon oil or a similar lubricant?

Comment: @bobthebuilder What do you mean by 'scratchy'? Is it the clicking sound you get while doing it with speed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two materials that you can use.

1. Standard insulating foam will work.
2. Aerogel will work magnificently. It is one of the least dense materials that mankind has created. Because of this, it is an amazing insulator.